# What is this line above the stack soft menu on my hp 50g?

Tags: calculator

I'm learning my new hp 50g and am seeing an odd line several pixels wide only above the stack soft menu. If I hit NXT to see the next page of menu options, the line goes away. If I am viewing a menu other than the default TOOL menu, there is no line. Any ideas what this is?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the meaning of the bar above the soft menu, it's telling the user that that option will take you to a 'sub-menu' of sorts. It's somewhat like a folder, where the options that do not have the bar above are simply commands.